# Alternative to Recursive Function

Tags: recursion, iteration

I have been working on MLM (multi level marketing) application. 
Below is the code snippet (not entire code) of recursive function which I had written in initial phase and was working properly. But now the MLM tree is too deep and recursive function stops. It says maximum nesting level exceeded. I increased nesting function call levels few times but now I dont want to increase it further as I know that's not right solution.

Can anyone suggest a alternative code (may be iterative) to me for this?

```
<?php
function findallpairs($username, $totalusers= 0)
{
$sql = "select username,package_id from tbl_user where 
    parent_id = '".$username."'      order by username";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{       
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {           
        $username = $row["username"];
        $totalusers++;

        $arrtmp = findallpairs($username, $totalusers);
        $totalusers = $arrtmp["totalusers"];
    }
}

$arrpoints["totalusers"] = $totalusers;

return $arrpoints;
}
?>
```

Note : Please remember my original code is too big but I have been pasting just the important aspect of the logic here.

It would be a great help for me if I find the alternative solution to this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

How deep are you going?

The day makes a mutliway tree within your sql database. Trees are recursive structures, and recursive code is what naturally fits.

You may be able use use what i'm calling quasi-memiozation.

This should be easy if you have the children listed in the DB structure. Take a result for all users with no childrin, memioize their value into a hash or tree with the key being the user ID and the value 1. Then just mass iterate over each user (or just the parents of memiozed entries) and if it has values memiozed for all its children, add them together and memoioze that value. Repeat the iteration until you find the root (a user with no parent)

If you don't have a record of children it's likely terribly inefficient.